# How do I load an image to an apk in delphi XE8

Tags: android, delphi, bitmap

I am working on an app in Delphi XE8.

When I run the program on my phone, it gives me an error:

> Loading bitmap failed(image.png)

My code works as follows:

```
if ListBox1.ItemIndex = 0 then
begin
  img.bitmap.LoadFromFile('Image.png');
  iMin:= Round(iNumber * 1);
  iMax:= Round(iNumber *13.24);
  iAvg:= Round(iNumber * 2.59);
  label7.Text:= inttostr(iMin);
  label5.Text:= inttostr(iAvg);
  label6.Text:= inttostr(iMax);
  label2.Text:= 'Minimum';
  label3.Text:= 'Average';
  label4.Text:= 'Maximum';
end
else
  ...
```

Please note the image is saved in the same folder as my program.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use relative paths. Always use absolute paths.

You need to use the [Deployment Manager](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Deployment_Manager) to deploy the image file to an appropriate folder on the phone, and then use the [`System.IOUtils.TPath`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TPath) class to locate that folder at runtime:

[Standard RTL Path Functions across the Supported Target Platforms](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Standard_RTL_Path_Functions_across_the_Supported_Target_Platforms)

On Android, deploy the image file to the `./assets/internal` folder, and then use the  `TPath.GetDocumentsPath()` method at runtime, as documented on this blog:

[Deploying and accessing local files on iOS and Android](http://community.embarcadero.com/article/articles-tutorials/151-ui/927-deploying-and-accessing-local-files-on-ios-and-android)

What the EDN documentation and blog both fail to mention is that you also need to add the `System.StartupCopy` unit to your app's `uses` clause.

```
uses
  ..., System.IOUtils, System.StartupCopy;

...

img.bitmap.LoadFromFile(TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'Image.png'));
```